# Postgres constraint for unique datetime range

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design, constraints, mutual-exclusion

My table has two columns:

1. `startsAt`
2. `endsAt`

Both hold date and time.
I want to make following constraint:

IF both columns are NOT NULL then range between startsAt and endsAt must not overlap with other ranges (from other rows).

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/75034/unique-constraint-to-enforce-max-one-null-per-item/75036#75036

Comment: I can't use `range` column - I have to operate on two columns: `startsAt` and `endsAt`.

Comment: Create a new column with datatype tsrange that takes startsAt and endsAt as input. A constraint on this new column fixes your problem.

Comment: You best edit the additional requirement into the question.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can keep your separate `timestamp` columns and still use an [**exclusion constraint**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html#SQL-CREATETABLE-EXCLUDE) on an expression:

```sql
CREATE TABLE tbl (
   tbl_id    serial PRIMARY KEY
 , starts_at timestamp
 , ends_at   timestamp
 , EXCLUDE USING gist (tsrange(starts_at, ends_at) WITH &&)  -- no overlap
);
```

[Constructing a `tsrange` value](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html#RANGETYPES-CONSTRUCT) without explicit bounds as `tsrange(starts_at, ends_at)` assumes default bounds: inclusive lower and exclusive upper - `'[)'`, which is typically best.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=d0c58af3af8084cc80eae52a5d2f0dbf)*
<sub>Old [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/6fd19/1)</sub>

Related:

- [Preventing adjacent/overlapping entries with EXCLUDE in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19504727/preventing-adjacent-overlapping-entries-with-exclude-in-postgresql/19505869#19505869)

#### Add constraint to existing table

```
ALTER TABLE tbl ADD CONSTRAINT tbl_no_overlapping_time_ranges
EXCLUDE USING gist (tsrange(starts_at, ends_at) WITH &&)
```

Syntax details are the same as for [`CREATE TABLE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html).

Comment: Could you describe how one could have the constraint tied to another column say 'client_id'?

Comment: @DanielNicoletti: Yes. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/20513792/939860 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/27348912/939860