# OVERLAPS operator to check multiples rows

Tags: postgresql, database-design, plpgsql, overlap

Currently I am using the overlaps operator so that users can't insert dates that overlap. I created this function:

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION overlap(docent_medewerkerscode1 CHARACTER(7),  
lokaal1 TEXT, groep_groepsnaam1 TEXT, startdatum1 timestamp, einddatum1 
timestamp)

RETURNS TEXT AS $$
DECLARE
    resultaat TEXT;
    rec rooster%rowtype;
BEGIN 
    FOR rec IN SELECT groep_groepsnaam = groep_groepsnaam1 OR lokaal =      
lokaal1 OR docent_medewerkerscode = docent_medewerkerscode1 FROM rooster 
  LOOP
        IF(startdatum1, einddatum1) OVERLAPS (startdatum, einddatum) FROM  
rooster THEN
           --IF startdatum1 BETWEEN startdatum AND einddatum AND einddatum1 BETWEEN startdatum AND einddatum FROM rooster THEN
            resultaat = 'tijd overlapt';
            RAISE 'Niet mogelijk tijd komt overeen met ingeplande tijd';
        END IF;
  END LOOP;

RETURN resultaat;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

The problem is that the overlap doesn't work on multiples rows.

> (ERROR:  query "SELECT (startdatum1, einddatum1) OVERLAPS (startdatum, einddatum) FROM rooster" returned more than one row)

I am looking for a way that let's the overlap check each row from the select query. Any of you guys that have an idea of what I can do?

Comment: As *always*, your version of Postgres, please. In the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The immediate cause for the error message is that the [plpgsql **`IF`** statement](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-CONDITIONALS) expects a **single** boolean expression, while your code returns a whole set of boolean expressions.

```
IF(startdatum1, einddatum1) OVERLAPS (startdatum, einddatum) FROM  
rooster THEN
```

is an ugly short form of:

```
IF (SELECT(startdatum1, einddatum1) OVERLAPS (startdatum, einddatum)
    FROM  rooster) THEN
```

and simply invalid this way. You would have to agggregate or use `EXISTS`:

```
IF EXISTS (
   SELECT 1 FROM  rooster r
   WHERE  (startdatum1, einddatum1) OVERLAPS (r.startdatum, r.einddatum)
   ) THEN ...
```

More importantly, an [**exclusion constraint**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createtable.html#SQL-CREATETABLE-EXCLUDE) is almost certainly the better solution for your problem (requires Postgres 9.0+):

- [Postgres constraint for unique datetime range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26735955/postgres-constraint-for-unique-datetime-range/26736759#26736759)
- [Preventing adjacent/overlapping entries with EXCLUDE in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19504727/preventing-adjacent-overlapping-entries-with-exclude-in-postgresql/19505869#19505869)

Comment: Thank you for advice, this will definitely help!