# Can I add a CHECK in my SQL CREATE TABLE script?

Tags: sql, postgresql, create-table

I created this table for my database.

```
CREATE TABLE Reservation
(
Reservation_Name SERIAL UNIQUE PRIMARY KEY,
User VARCHAR(64) DEFAULT 'Member', FOREIGN KEY(User) REFERENCES User(Email)
ON UPDATE CASCADE
ON DELETE SET DEFAULT,
Location INT, FOREIGN KEY(Location) REFERENCES Place(Id_Location)
ON UPDATE CASCADE
ON DELETE NO ACTION,
Start_Date DATE NOT NULL,
Check_In TIME(1) DEFAULT '10:00:00',
End_Date DATE NOT NULL,
Check_Out TIME(1) DEFAULT '18:00:00',
CHECK(Start_Date >= End_Date),
Deleted BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE
);
```

How can I insert a Check that doesn't allow to add a reservation if there's already another one with the same Start_Date and the same End_Date end the same location?

Comment: Why would you only want to check the exact start/end dates rather than any overlap?

Comment: I don't want that 2 different users could make a reservation for the same Place in the same days

Comment: @Alberto - but it's fine if one makes a reservation from 21st - 23rd and the other makes a reservation from 22nd - 24th? Interesting take on common concepts of reservations if so.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Sorry, you're right. I don't want that way you said could be possible. How could I avoid this?

Comment: This is probably answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26735955/postgres-constraint-for-unique-datetime-range

Comment: Look into table constraints

Comment: Unrelated, but: `unique` is not necessary if you also use `primary key`

Comment: you are looking for an exclusion constraint: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-EXCLUSION

Answer (score 1):

You can symply add a constraint to the table.

`Alter Table Reservations Add Constraint unique_reservation Unique(Location,StartDate,EndDate);`

You will need a trigger for this. Look at the above code :

```
CREATE TRIGGER no_overlap
BEFORE INSERT
   ON Reservation FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
        SET @overlaps = ( SELECT count(*) FROM Reservation WHERE ( ( NEW.Start_Date >= Start_Date AND NEW.Start_Date <= End_Date AND NEW.Location = Location) || ( NEW.End_Date >= Start_Date AND NEW.End_Date <= End_Date AND NEW.Location = Location)));
        IF @overlaps > 0 THEN
          SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET
          MYSQL_ERRNO = 31000,
          MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Unable to insert an overlapping reservation';
       END IF;

END;

INSERT INTO Reservation (Location,Start_Date,End_Date) VALUES(1,'2020-12-13','2020-12-16');
INSERT INTO Reservation (Location,Start_Date,End_Date) VALUES(1,'2020-12-14','2020-12-17');
```

The first insert will succeed while the second one will fail with the corresponding error message if the dates overlap :

```
SQL Error [31000] [45000]: (conn=10) Unable to insert an overlapping reservation
```

By the way, I think you have an error in your table definition. Instead of **CHECK(Start_Date >= End_Date),** I think you meant **CHECK(Start_Date <= End_Date),**

Let me know if it helps.

Note : I did this on MariaDB but you can apply the same for any SQL DB.

Comment: Can I also avoid that someone could make a reservation from 21st - 23rd and the other makes a reservation from 22nd - 24th for the same place?

Comment: This isn't valid Postgres syntax.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an exclusion constraint:

```
CREATE EXTENSION btree_gist;

ALTER TABLE reservation ADD EXCLUDE USING gist (
   location WITH =,
   daterange(start_date, end_date, '[]') WITH &&
);
```

The extension is required so that you can create a GiST index on an `integer` column, and `&&` is the "overlaps" operator for range types.

Answer (score 1):

This works in sql server.  I don't have access at the moment to check against postgres. You will need to run in two different batches after creating your table

First

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.HasOverlap (
    @locationId int, @start datetime, @end datetime)
RETURNS VARCHAR(5)
AS
BEGIN
    IF (SELECT count(*) FROM dbo.Reservation WHERE Location = @locationId 
        and (
            @start between Start_Date and End_Date 
            or 
            @end between Start_Date and End_Date
            or
            (@start <=Start_Date and @end>=End_Date )
            )
            ) >1
        return 1
    return 0
END
```

Second

```
Alter Table dbo.Reservation 
with check add Constraint Check_Overlap
check (dbo.HasOverlap(Location, Start_Date, End_Date)=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the composite primary key concept in MySQL Database. Its disable to insert duplicate items in specific columns.

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD CONSTRAINT constraint_name PRIMARY KEY (Start_Date, End_Date, Location)
```

Comment: That answers the original question, but not his claried requirements that he doesn't want any overlap

Comment: I believe, it is working for sure, even overlap also needs some extra done, but its work is done in the database side.

Comment: @DayaStark where should I write your piece of code in my exemple? And does it avoid the possibility to add two reservation in the same period for the same place?

Comment: its SQL code which is run in the workbench query editor. You just add constraints for unique composite primary key.