# How I can define this constraint?

Tags: database, postgresql, database-design, constraints

I am designing a database for a parking lot in Postgres. I need to define a constraint (or similar) to verify the `Id_Lot` in Ticket is empty in the table `"Lot"`.

How I can do it?

The relevant tables are:

Ticket:

```
"Id_Ticket"         serial PRIMARY KEY,
"Date_Entrance"     date NOT NULL,
"Time_Entrance"     time without time zone NOT NULL,
"License_plate"     varchar(6) NOT NULL references "Vehicle"("L_Plate"), 
"Id_Lot"            varchar(4) NOT NULL references "Lot"("Code")
```

Lot:

```
"Code"              varchar(4) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
"Type"              varchar(5) NOT NULL,
"Empty"             boolean NOT NULL
```

Comment: Probably with a constraint trigger. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-createtrigger.html

Comment: You don't store the time of exit. Why?

Comment: I think that I wouldn't know when a customer is going to return... So I will save this information in a table "Bill" that's the final payment.

Comment: Verify `"Id_Lot"` is "empty" at the time of the check (once), or verify it is "empty" permanently? It really depends on the specifics of your model.

Comment: Yeah, I'm sorry for that... Thank you.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: you should really avoid those dreaded quoted identifiers. They are much more trouble than they are worth it. https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_upper_case_table_or_column_names

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Solution for what you ask

Assuming you want to enforce that:

1. `"Id_Lot"` actually exists in `"Lot"."Code"`. -> FK constraint
2. `"Lot"."Empty"` for the spot is `TRUE` at the time of the check only.

You *could* do this with a [`NOT VALID`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altertable.html) `CHECK` constraint using a fake `IMMUTABLE` function to check on the other table. Details:

- [Disable all constraints and table checks while restoring a dump](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/75635/3684)

But your data model is shaky in a number of aspects. I would suggest a much cleaner approach.

#### Cleaner design with exclusion constraint

Don't store whether a lot is currently empty redundantly with the lot. That's very error prone and susceptible to concurrency issues. Enforce that each lot can only be taken once at a time with an **[exclusion constraint](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-EXCLUSION)**. For that to work, save the time of exit in `ticket`, additionally.

```
CREATE TABLE lot (
  lot_id   varchar(4) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY  -- I would use integer if possible
, lot_type text NOT NULL
);
```

No redundant current state in the `lot` table.

For the exclusion constraint to work, you need the additional module [**btree_gist**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/btree-gist.html). Detailed instructions:

- ['one-to-many' relation integrity issue for time ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20420410/one-to-many-relation-integrity-issue-for-time-ranges/20513792#20513792)
- [Store the day of the week and time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19895140/store-the-day-of-the-week-and-time/19897592#19897592)

```
CREATE TABLE ticket (
  ticket_id  serial PRIMARY KEY
, during     tsrange NOT NULL
, license_plate text NOT NULL REFERENCES "Vehicle"("L_Plate"),
, lot_id     int NOT NULL REFERENCES  lot
, CONSTRAINT lot_uni_ticket EXCLUDE USING gist (lot_id WITH =, during WITH &&)
, CONSTRAINT during_lower_bound_not_null CHECK (NOT lower_inf(during))
, CONSTRAINT during_bounds CHECK (lower_inc(during) AND NOT upper_inc(during))
);
```

- Using a timestamp range data type [**`tsrange`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html) for the parking duration `during`.
  Enter with upper bound NULL, when the car enters. Update with upper bound when the car exits.
  Among other things, this also makes it possible for cars to park multiple days.
- Some additional `CHECK` constraints to enforce basic rules on `during`:

  - Inclusive lower bound, exclusive upper bound to stay consistent.
  - The lower bound (entrance) can never be missing.

    - [PostgreSQL tsrange: is it correct for lower_inf('(-infinity,today)'::tsrange) to be false?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27103608/postgresql-tsrange-is-it-correct-for-lower-inf-infinity-todaytsrange-to/27105923#27105923)

Related:

- [How to find first free start times from reservations in Postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26608683/how-to-find-first-free-start-times-from-reservations-in-postgres/26613323#26613323)