# Optimized way of looping through 2 tables with one being very big

Tags: sql, postgresql, date-range, postgresql-performance

Basically, I'm working with data from icu patients and studying a particular disease. For every patient, I have the disease stage during all of the patient's stay in the ICU, as you can see here:

[timeline table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bRUd2.png)

The other table I have it's the **records** table:

[records table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nDHiy.png)

I simply want to add to the records table the stage of the disease when that measure was made, which can be made simply by `records.charttime BETWEEN timeline.starts AND timeline.ends`, but I want to do it in the most optimized way possible due to the **records** table having nearly **100 million rows**, and the **timeline** table over **100k rows**.

I read about the usage of `CURSOR`, but I don't know if it makes sense using `CURSOR` in this case, or maybe I'm just adding complexity and it can be solved easily using `JOIN`.

What's the best solution?

Comment: Please provide table definition and sample data as plain text, not a link to an image. And always declare your version of Postgres. Consider instructions here: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info

Comment: Are you trying to add a new column to the "records" table and populate it?  Or are you just trying to view the results of a join dynamically without altering the structure of your tables?

Answer (score 1):

Looping with an explicit cursor is typically slower than a plain join. Postgres will do the looping for you, most likely with a nested loop in the query plan.

```
SELECT r.*, t.stage
FROM   records       r
LEFT   JOIN timeline t ON r.icustay_id = t.icustay_id -- guessing ... ?
                      AND r.charttime >= t.starts
                      AND r.charttime <  t.ends;      -- excl. upper bound
```

<strike>`BETWEEN`</strike> would (probably incorrectly) include the upper bound.

The `LEFT JOIN` preserves *all* rows from `records`, even if no match is found in `timeline`.

I assume ranges in `timeline` cannot overlap? Else, you get duplicated rows. There should probably be an exclusion constraint for table `timeline`. See:

- [Preventing adjacent/overlapping entries with EXCLUDE in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19504727/preventing-adjacent-overlapping-entries-with-exclude-in-postgresql/19505869#19505869)

Since you are processing the whole table anyway, indexes won't be of much help.

However, since your `records` table is so big, you may not have enough memory available to process everything in RAM, so it might pay to process partitions of your `records` table at a time. The best way to partition depends on undisclosed details, most importantly the physical sort order of rows in both tables.

Comment: I think the join condition also needs include `timeline.icustay_id=records.icustay_id`.

Comment: @jjanes: Yes, the column names suggest as much. I added it.