# How to return all entries "from the current year"?

Tags: sql, postgresql, range-types

I have a `tsrange` column named time_range. I want to get all rows from my user from the current year. So when a row is like this:

```
("2024-01-01, 2025-02-02")
```

I also want it because 2024 is included. With a normal timestamp column I know how to do it but with `tsrange` I have no idea how that works.

My current query:

```
SELECT time_range
FROM holidays
WHERE user_id = 1
AND time_range <@ tsrange(start_time, end_time, '()')
```

Result:

```
("2024-02-02", "2024-04-05")
("2024-12-02", "2025-01-02")
("2025-03-03", "2025-04-04")
```

I want to all rows where any part of 2024 is included. So the first and second one, but not the third.

Comment: Please show your exact definition of the column `time_range`, and (always) your version of Postgres. And define "from the current year" / "because 2024 is included" *exactly*. Do you mean the whole year is included? Or do you mean ranges that overlap with the year in any way?

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Hi, I edited my code and my query so you can better usntand it, and my pg version is 15.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want the ["overlap" operator `&&`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-range.html#RANGE-OPERATORS-TABLE) for range types.

To get all entries where `time_range` overlaps with the year 2024 in any way:

```sql
SELECT time_range
FROM   holidays
WHERE  user_id = 1
AND    time_range && '[2024-1-1, 2025-1-1)';  -- tsrange type
```

Note how the lower bound in my range is included (`[`), but upper bound is excluded (`)`).
Related:

- [Preventing adjacent/overlapping entries with EXCLUDE in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19504727/preventing-adjacent-overlapping-entries-with-exclude-in-postgresql/19505869#19505869)

Aside: If there is a remote chance that different time zones might be involved, you'll want to use `tstzrange` instead of `tsrange` ...